# Where are the general rules for tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I just proposed a synonym for the laravel-4 tag: laravel-4.1 - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel-4/synonyms

I did that because 4 and 4.1 are very similar. In my opinion, changes in the framework are not enough to separate them that way and this might bring some confusion all around.

It's not like you do things in a completely different way in 4.1, but there were a lot of improvements on things we use. Some small changes, yeah, but no big deals. Converting your app to 4.1 takes around 10 minutes, so a new tag for 4.1 will separate them too much in the long run.

But where are the tag synonym rules? I would like to understand better how they work here.

Comment: Did you see [questions/tagged/tag-synonyms?sort=frequent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms?sort=frequent&pageSize=50)?

Comment: I'm trying to have the 4.1 tag merged into the 4 tag - as there is no purpose for it. See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223786/195355